# Which equipments can i buy to record sounds of animals and birds?

Tags: audio-recording, audio

My friend is doing a acoustic project related to his studies. He needs to record high quality sounds from animals and birds. I don't know anything about recording audio as i am a programmer. So please suggest what equipments to buy and do the recordings in the outdoor such as a village or jungle(the type of microphone and any other devices needed amplify the sound) and also what software to use to do more processing if needed(I can learn and help him on using a software). A help would be much grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are serious about it, want pro quality, portability and integrated mics

The [Tascam DR-100 MK II](http://tascam.com/product/dr-100mkii/) it's an excellent choice!

You have great sound, four integrated mics and phantom power to connect two professional condenser mics

It's the best I could find.... Hope this helps, and let in know if you find a better option....

You can even set it on auto record so it senses when the animals are making sounds and stuff like that!

And for the software, you can use any free wave editor like audacity

Comment: http://tascam.com/product/dr-100mkii/